# How to find a problem when Chrome Developer Tools doesn't show one

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I've been learning how to use the Chrome Developer Tools (CDT) for debugging.

I'm trying to add some functionality to an application written in HTML/Javascript/jQuery/MySQL. Basically it loads an Ajax created table from MySQL using jQuery, along the way it checks a cookie for a numeric list representing the columns to toggle() on or off.

When first loaded it checks the cookie and dutifully loads the requested columns. But when I refresh the table (not a page reload) and it again reads the cookie it momentarily shows the columns but then immediately toggles them off again.

Walking through the javascript with CDT brings me out of my code and into jQuery v3.3.1 at the line that starts //callback or about line number 9523 of the uncompressed version. After bouncing around a bit it stops and my page is displayed without the additional columns. But no errors are shown in CDT and nothing it does "looks" wrong to my eyes.

I know the first thing many of you want is the javascript, but its quite a large program so I don't know how to provide a non-working, working model if you get the drift. Besides I'm more interested in learning to use CDT to figure out problems like this. But I don't know what to do next, I've watched a bunch of YouTube videos, I've asked a few friends, but none of that is helping much.

It appears now that the problem of it "flashing" is happening in the 'complete' portion of the callback function @ line 9548 in jQuery-3.3.1.js. Isolating it by commenting it out makes things worse, nothing seems to work. So I'm back to square one.

What should I be looking at and for in CDT?

Comment: This sounds like the the common issue of screen flashing (there's a different term for it, but I'm forgetting it) where the default html shows elements and then the javascript hides them.  The typical way to "fix" this is to hide them by default, and let the javascript show them when they are needed, thus removing the case where it briefly shows them and you do not need to show them.

Comment: @Taplar I really liked your answer, so I tried it. I put the same code that toggles the columns in, twice. And I tried it in a number of places including immediately before and again after. Unfortunately this didn't solve the issue. Screen Flashing is a good description of what is happening so I'll stay on that idea for a while.

Comment: It sounds like perhaps you misunderstood by what I meant by hiding them by default.  What that refers to would be to use css to style the elements to be hidden by default, as soon as the page loads.  Then it becomes the javascripts job to unhide them when necessary.

Comment: @Taplar I'll give this a try too. In the mean time. It appears now that the problem of it "flashing" is happening in the 'complete' portion of the callback function @ line 9548 in jQuery-3.3.1.js. Isolating it by commenting it out makes things worse, nothing seems to work. So I'm back to square one.

Comment: @Taplar Turns out I already was doing your suggestion like this;      .toggleG, .toggleE, .toggleLAT, .toggleLON, .toggleLN, .toggleTOD, .toggleCREDS, 
.toggleCNTY, .toggleSTATE, .toggleDIST, .togglePhone, .toggleX {
 display:none;
 width: 0px;
 height: 0px;
}

Comment: As I understand it, you're not seeing any errors in devtools because there are none.  Flashing isn't an error, it is just a consequence of displaying and hiding and refreshing things in the order that the code is doing.  So you simply need to trace through the various stages of your code and find out why the flashing is happening.  It is going to be hard for anyone to help without seeing any of your code.  See if you can create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Don'tPanic  I have a better idea of what you two have been saying. I just wasn't understanding. No errors means... no errors... it means I'm telling the code what to do so I need to relook at what that is. Deterring where I'm telling it to do each step and fix it. I'm close to that now. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: First I’d try to write a test case: imitate what the AJAX should return, and see whether that shows the same symptoms. That would help to localize the problem in the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

If you have code base try to use `debugger;` where you want to put break point to debug for JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're interested in understand *how* to use CDT to debug js/html/css issues in your DOM, my answer will be focusing on *that*, and not what your exact issue may or may not be. Note that display issues in your DOM are not errors that would typically show up in your browser console – a perfect candidate for CDT debugging.

One incredibly useful technique in CDT is the use of the `break on ...` functionality. I'll walk you through how to use it, and how to leverage it to diagnose your particular issue. Additional info on what I'm about to cover may be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints#dom).

1. Right-click directly on the element on your page that is disappearing, and click `Inspect`.
2. Initiate the database refresh which causes the table to disappear, while also keep an eye on your [DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html) tree open in dev tools.
3. Watch for how the DOM changes as a result of the action above; which elements were changed and how. Questions to ask are: "Was an element hidden?", "Was an element removed?". Typically, changes to the DOM tree will be briefly highlighted in purple by CDT when changed.
4. If the change is an element removal or addition, try to narrow down in the DOM tree the lowest (most specific) parent element directly under which the changes to your DOM are occurring. If it is an attribute modification (i.e. `display: none`, `visibility: hidden`, etc.), find the element to which this change is occurring. You may need to repeat the above steps a few times before you can accurately pick up on the change.
5. Refresh the page.
6. Back in the CDT DOM tree, right-click the element from step 4 and: if the element is the parent, click `Break on... > subtree modifications`. If it is the resulting element of an attribute change, right-click this element and select `Break on... > attribute modifications`.
   [image: Break on...]
7. Initiate the database refresh which causes the disappearance. If all went well, CDT should catch on your breakpoint and point you to the current javascript function which initiated the change to the DOM. You should also see a call stack which displays the chain of function calls leading up to the current function call.
8. You won't always happen upon a very helpful function as a result of the steps above. You may land on a low-level library function (i.e. jQuery.js). In that case, follow the call stack back to the last user-written .js file, and investigate. This is most always the culprit. Otherwise, follow the steps outlined [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#stepping) to continue stepping through your code until you come across a likely culprit.

Hopefully, this info will point you in the right direction, good luck!